# EmguCV DLL Not Found Exception -Unable to find cvextern?

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, emgucv

To start,this is not another blind Emgu CV DLL Issue among the ones asked in SO and around the web.I have researched this issue and cannot find a solution.

I have updated the EmguCV version which i use in one of my projects to the latest version(3.4.3).Eveything works fine on the Dev Machine and on a Windows 10 machine.But when it comes to Windows 7 X64 Spack1 EmguCv throws up the never ending `DLL not found Exception`.
I have had this issue when using the older version,which went away by installing the ***Visual Studio Redistributable*** .The current version seems to use Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable as there is a DLL file (14.0) in the EmguDir.I have tried installing the x86 version of 2015 and both x86 and x64 version of the 2017 VC Redistributable package.(My app is x86).I have also copied the x86 and x64 folders to the application directory(The older version seems to work fine without these folders, i just copied the contents of the x86 folder to the app dir).

[image]
[image]

The same error occurs again.I'm stuck here.Kindly help me out

```
 ************** Exception Text **************
    System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'cvextern': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

The other DLLs (Emgu's are packed to main exe using a packer).

Answer (score 6):

Install using Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio 2019 **Tools> NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console**

and Install this

- Install-Package Emgu.CV
- Install-Package Emgu.CV.runtime.windows

And everything worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks.  I had not installed the runtime, and that was the problem for me.  EMGU CV has the worst documentation.

Comment: is it for windows? How to fix it for mac m1?

Answer (score 2):

I also have the same issues. On this forum [emgucv](http://www.emgu.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=16223), I don't know why `cvextern.dll` from emgucv 3.4.3 that cannot load cvextern ('cause unable to find cvextern), and you allowed to use file `cvextern.dll` from emgucv 3.4.2 (make sure you choose x64 / x86), copy at `/bin/Debug` and this file automatically found in `/bin/Debug/x86` or `/bin/Debug/x64`when you finished build the program at Visual Studio.

Hope this help.

Comment: from where did you copy the dlls. after the nuget-install they are only in c:\users\username\.nuget\packages\emgu...., so not in the project

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, please **be sure to add nuget package to PROJECT not the SOLUTION**. If not, you can have 'file not found' problems.